# Find system idle time using any system call in microseconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, performance, c, system-calls

For the perf analysis and to make decision based on system and app performance I need to find the idle time of system. I want the precise value in microseconds.

I know that I can get the value in jiffies using procfs /proc/uptime but I heard reading procfs has extra overhead and can be slow as these files are created on demand basis.

Please correct me if I am wrong but this value is in jiffies which is not as precise as value return by function clock_gettime which I am using to query system uptime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME), process's and thread's time spent in kernel and system. Same thing applies to /proc/stat (value is in jiffies)

I am asking any other any way to query the process idle time and since other value (uptime. kernel/user space time is in mico-sec) so I was expecting the idle time in microseconds only.

Any help and comments would be appreciated.

Comment: If you care about microseconds, then give your definition of *the idle time of system* of precision matching the unit chosen.

Comment: I am newbie so If you think I am doing something wrong or talking nonsense, please correct me :-)

Comment: The fact is: i don't understand what is your question !

Comment: I am asking any other any way to query the process idle time and since other value (uptime. kernel/user space time is in mico-sec) so I was expecting the idle time in microseconds only.